# How to fix Dialog Fragment memory leak?

Tags: java, android, leakcanary

I'm trying to destroy my dialog fragment but after `onDestroy` is called leakcanary notification is appeared and this log print for me.

I take this error with `BottomSheetDialogFragment` too.

I'm setting all object nullable and destroy all of them in `onDestroyView`

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Thread object
│
├─ com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.n instance
│    Leaking: NO (ac↓ is not leaking)
│    Thread name: 'RenderDrive'
│    ↓ n.e
├─ com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.p instance
│    Leaking: NO (ac↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ p.f
├─ com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.ac instance
│    Leaking: NO (RecyclerView↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of app.delivery.client.AndroidApplication
│    ↓ View.mAttachInfo
├─ android.view.View$AttachInfo instance
│    Leaking: NO (RecyclerView↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ View$AttachInfo.mScrollContainers
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: NO (RecyclerView↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ ArrayList[1]
├─ androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainFragment↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mID = R.id.tabLayout
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of app.delivery.client.features.MainActivity.View.
│    MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ RecyclerView.mAdapter
├─ app.delivery.client.features.Main.Main.Adapter.TabAdapter instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ TabAdapter.iSelectTab
├─ app.delivery.client.features.Main.Main.View.MainFragment instance
│    Leaking: NO (ProfileFragment↓ is not leaking and Fragment#mFragmentManager
│    is not null)
│    parentActivity instance of app.delivery.client.features.MainActivity.View.
│    MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ MainFragment.profileFragment
├─ app.delivery.client.features.Main.Main.Profile.View.ProfileFragment instance
│    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    parentActivity instance of app.delivery.client.features.MainActivity.View.
│    MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ ProfileFragment.addBalanceDialog
│                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
╰→ app.delivery.client.features.Main.AddBalance.View.AddBalanceDialog instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because app.delivery.client.
​     features.Main.AddBalance.View.AddBalanceDialog received
​     Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
​     Retaining 3.3 kB in 101 objects
​     key = 9f9e28af-1fdf-4810-9940-26735e1b2d1d
​     watchDurationMillis = 39126
​     retainedDurationMillis = 34125
```